# How to Bind to property of the window from popup shown using InteractionRequest in WPF+prism?

Tags: wpf, binding, prism

I am creating an application using WPF and Prism.  My intention is to show a popup window on a button click.  I am using interaction request for achieving the same.  I do not want to show the default window title but would like to show the title in a control inside the view used by the popup.  I tried to use binding with  'RelaviteSource' setting RelativeSourceType = Window.  But the binding is not working even thoug the visual tree displayed by VS2017 contains a Window.

## MainView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="PopupTests.Views.MainView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PopupTests"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ShowPopupRequest}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <local:PopupView/>
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid >
        <Button Margin="20" Content="Click Here" Command="{Binding OnClick}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

## MainViewModel.CS

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace PopupTests.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public ICommand OnClick { get; }
        public InteractionRequest<INotification> ShowPopupRequest { get; } = new InteractionRequest<INotification>();
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            OnClick = new DelegateCommand(OnClicked);
        }

        private void OnClicked()
        {
            var notification = new Notification() { Title = "Test Titile", Content = null };
            ShowPopupRequest.Raise(notification);
        }
    }
}
```

## PopupView

```
<UserControl x:Class="PopupTests.PopupView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="blk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="151"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I expect the title 'Test Title' which is displayed by the window is displayed in the text box as well.  But unfortunately the binding is not working and I am getting a trace message as follows

*Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Title; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')*

What am I missing here?

## Update

After some more trial and error, I feel this is due to some timing issue.  If I add the following code in the 'Loaded' event, the value is appering

```
        var binding = blk.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty);
        blk.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding.ParentBinding);
```

But I do not want to have code behind and would prefer a xaml only solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you think this is a timing issue, then trying add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the Text binding for your TextBlock.

Comment: I have already tried and it did not help.  My guess after a few experiments is that the relative source is not getting re-evaluated after the view is assigned as child of the window in PopupWindowAction.  If there is any way to force this re-evaluation, the problem should get solved.